# radio buttons won't check / uncheck

Tags: javascript, html, forms, radio-button

I have some radio buttons in my web page.
when clicking the radio button it checks but when i click again it doesn't un-check.
i tried to add a JS function onclick

```
document.querySelectorAll('input[type="radio"]').forEach(x => x.addEventListener('click',function(){
        if(this.checked == true){
            this.checked = false;
        }
        else {
            this.checked = true;
        }
    }))
```

when I added this method it allowed my to uncheck but didn't allow me to check any of them!
what can I be missing?

these are my checkboxes:

```
<input type="radio" id="name" name="name"><br>
<input type="radio" id="age" name="age"><br>
<input type="radio" id="email" name="email"><br>
```

Comment: put a semicolon in the end.

Comment: JavaScript does not require semicolons necessarily. I tried but it didn't make any difference.

Comment: Refer this, https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_sel_radio

Comment: for the link you have shared, the radios have the same name therefore one gets unchecked when you check the other. i.e. you can only select one. in my case the radios are completely unrelated and each of them refers to something different. i am trying to be able to check or un-check any. maybe all. maybe none.

Comment: if you want select only one you should give the same names. and select several radio buttons you should give different names in my answer.  but in the second condition it's better to use checkbox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They all have different `name` attribute values - therefore they can *only* be checked (because they're not comparing to another sibling radio value). I think you might be looking for `type="checkbox"` instead:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="name" name="name"><br>
<input type="checkbox" id="age" name="age"><br>
<input type="checkbox" id="email" name="email"><br>
```

Comment: @laylal00 Feel free to mark as having answered your question to help those that might come across the same issue in the future :)

Answer (score 2):

**Example:** Hold down `Ctrl` (`⌘` on mac) key to uncheck.

```js
var radios = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
for(i=0; i<radios.length; i++ ) {
    radios[i].onclick = function(e) {
        if(e.ctrlKey || e.metaKey) {
            this.checked = false;
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="test" value="1" />
<input type="radio" name="test" value="2" checked="checked" />
<input type="radio" name="test" value="3" />
```

Comment: can i know what does e refer to? is it something i need to define on my browser or just a variable ? because e shows undefined for this solution

Comment: `e` is the short var reference for event object which will be passed to event handlers.

Answer (score 2):

Use `<input type="checkbox"`, not `<input type="radio"`.
Radio button is used where you have to select one of some options (which must have same `name`).

For example,

```html
<input type="radio" name="gender" id="male" value="male"> <br>
<input type="radio" name="gender" id="female" value="female"> <br>
<input type="radio" name="gender" id="other" value="other">
```

Know more about [radio button](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_type_radio.asp) and [check boxes](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_type_checkbox.asp).

Answer (score 2):

```js
 document.querySelectorAll('input[type="radio"]').forEach(x => x.addEventListener('click',function(){
    if(this.value == 0){
          this.checked = true;
          document.querySelectorAll('input[type="radio"]').forEach(x=>x.value=0);
          this.value = 1;
      }
      else {

          this.checked = false;
          document.querySelectorAll('input[type="radio"]').forEach(x=>x.value=0);
          this.value = 0;
      }      
}))
```

```html
<input type="radio" value="0" id="name" name="test"><br>
<input type="radio" value="0" id="age" name="test"><br>
<input type="radio" value="0" id="email" name="test"><br>
```

Answer (score 0):

This code allows the user to deselect a radio button:

```
  document.querySelectorAll('input[type="radio"]').forEach(x => x.addEventListener('click',function(){
    if(! this.value0 || this.value0 == 0){
      this.checked = true;
      document.querySelectorAll('input[type="radio"][name="'+this.name+'"]').forEach(x=>x.value0=0);
      this.value0 = 1;
    } else {
      this.checked = false;
      document.querySelectorAll('input[type="radio"][name="'+this.name+'"]').forEach(x=>x.value0=0);
      this.value0 = 0;
    }
  }))
```

It improves the answer of Sato Takeru.